# ensuring FIFO while using SQS in PHP

Tags: php, amazon-sqs

Does anyone know of an elegant way to ensure FIFO when it comes to polling down the messages from the queue. PHP is the language I am using. If anyone has any code they can share it would be great and thanks ahead of time

Comment: A queue is FIFO by definition. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: @MikeW Amazon's Simple Queue Service is **not** FIFO.

Comment: @ceejayoz I learn something new every day...

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I was speaking about SQS queue and no its not FIFO as a regular queue. I wish it was :)

Answer (score 3):

**edit:** This is now available.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/11/amazon-sqs-introduces-fifo-queues-with-exactly-once-processing-and-lower-prices-for-standard-queues/

---

<sup>https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/</sup>

> <sup>**Q: Does Amazon SQS provide first-in-first-out (FIFO) access to messages?**</sup>
>
> <sup>No, Amazon SQS does not guarantee FIFO access to messages in Amazon SQS queues, mainly because of the distributed nature of the Amazon SQS. If you require specific message ordering, you should design your application to handle it.</sup>

Comment: I totally agree that by default SQS doesn't guarantee FIFO. I was curious however if someone has written a nice workaround in PHP to mitigate that somehow? I know that IronMQ has managed to ensure that one never gets the same message twice and yes I know they are not the same systems. I am just trying to find an elegant solution/workaround in PHP before abandoning the SQS choice totally. So if anyone has tried something that worked I would appreciate the help :)

Comment: @user3662429 I really wouldn't waste time trying to engineer a workaround here. There are plenty of FIFO queues, both hosted and do-it-yourself, that it's really not worth the effort.

Comment: This is now supported: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/11/amazon-sqs-introduces-fifo-queues-with-exactly-once-processing-and-lower-prices-for-standard-queues/

Comment: @ThomasK Yes! Updated the answer accordingly.